# JavaScript splice() not working

Tags: javascript

```
for(var i = 0; i < this.phrases.length; i++) {
    console.log('sort ' + this.phrases[i]);
    console.log('sort length' + this.phrases.length);
    if(this.phrases[i] == null) {
        var s = this.phrases.splice(i, 1);
        console.log('splice ' + this.phrases[i]);
        console.log('splice length ' + this.phrases.length);
    }
}
```

I have an array (`this.phrases`). I made the phrase that I want to remove equal to null in another section. The first log prints `null`, the second log also prints `null`. Why is it not getting spliced?  This is also sometimes the last item in an array. Are you not able to splice an array with only one element? The same thing happens, however if it is not the last item in `this.phrases`.

**Edit:** `s` also does not seem to get set to any value.

**Edit:** The two length logs I added print the same number.

Edit: That's not actually true. Weird things are happening with the lengths, probably not involving this section of code.  I just want to know if I'm using splice() correctly.

Comment: When an element is removed with `.splice()`, the rest of the array's elements shifts down an index, but `i` continues incrementing regardless of these shifts.

Comment: But it seems that nothing gets spliced at all.  The array has the same number of elements before and after.

Comment: The `length` should change some, but the loop may not remove every `null` without adjusting `i` to counter the `i++`. http://jsfiddle.net/7UWew/ vs. http://jsfiddle.net/Q55nr/. You could also use [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) as long as you don't need the mutation aspect of `.splice()`. http://jsfiddle.net/7nmpE/

Comment: Easier would be to simply loop backwards.  http://jsfiddle.net/FjGAW/ . (Easier than the increment with decrement on splice; obviously `filter` us much simpler overall.)

Answer (score 1):

Switch these two lines:

```
var s = this.phrases.splice(i,1);

console.log('splice ' + this.phrases[i]);
```

To this:

```
console.log('splice ' + this.phrases[i]);

this.phrases.splice(i, 1);

i--;
```

Comment: Note the `p` in the method name. [`.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) is a mutator method.

Comment: I don't want this.phrases to equal what was spliced, I want it to equal what remains in the array after the splice.

Comment: Sorry, I made a confusion with slice. @JonathanLonowski thanks.

Comment: @michaelAdam after your splice you need to stay at the same i-th position, so you must step one i unit backwards, because the for will increment it after. suppose you delete element at index 2 in the next iteration i will be 3 but your element at index 3 is now in at your index 2.

Comment: I don't understand how this worked in this exact context because there is only ever one element that I am deleting, but this worked.

Comment: Do you know why this would matter if I am only removing one element?

Comment: @michaelAdam If you are removing just one, it doesn't matter much... but then, when you call console.log('splice ' + this.phrases[i]); if your i-th element just removed happened to be you last one in the array, you could get an exception, because you accessed a position out of bounds of the array! That's why I told you to switch those lines.

Answer (score 0):

```
const indexOfValue = treeSelectDataTemp.findIndex((item: any) => item.value === deleteIndexId[d]);

 console.log("  ###########  deleted indexOfValue ", indexOfValue);
 if (indexOfValue !== -1) {
    treeSelectDataTemp.splice(indexOfValue, 1);
 }
```